# How to retrieve users' IP and geolocation on CloudFlare?

Tags: php, cloudflare

I read on Cloudflare website it's possible to get all information using SERVER variables. There is a list with cf-ipcity, cf-iplongitude, cf-iplatitude, cf-region and so one.

I'm trying to get city, region and lat/long information about the visitor, but is always empty.

Just Cf-Ipcountry, Cf-Ray,  Cf-Connecting-Ip, Cf-Ipcountry, and Cf-Visitor isn´t empty.

I'm a Cloudflare Pro customer.

Any ideia?

I tried getting information using a simple PHP code and listing all server variables.

```
<?php
foreach ($_SERVER as $strName => $mixValue) {
echo $strName , ' = ', $mixValue, '<BR>';
}
```

And i switch on the IP Geolocation on Network Cloudflare dash.

Comment: In the provided code, `mixValue` should be `$mixValue`

Comment: Hello Chris. Thanks for answering. I fixed that, but it's just a typo here.

Comment: “I tried getting information” - what happens when you run that code, are you seeing some information at least? Also, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes. Cloudflare create a sort of proxy and share some informations like Cf-Ipcountry and Cf-Visitor. If I turn off the Cloudflare proxy, i can use the geolocation shared by my hosting platform.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if there was another proxy in the middle, like if you had an Nginx instance routing to Apache, then it is possible that headers aren't being forwarded

Comment: All IP addresses or only particular IP addresses have empty city?

Comment: No. No. I'm using google cloud platform. Headers are forwarded.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes. I don't saw any requests with.